# classList Value throws error with New Date function

Tags: javascript, class, date

When I change the classlist value it throws an error on the New Date function and I don't get how they cause each other but only about 60% of the time, the rest of the time when I run the project it runs just fine without any errors so I'm completely befuddled.

```js
const replay = document.getElementById("replay");
function updatebuttons(){
  playbicons.forEach(icon => icon.classList.toggle('hidden'))
  if(vid.paused){
    playb.setAttribute('data-title', 'Play (k)')
  }else{
    playb.setAttribute("data-title",'Pause (k)')
  }
  //Here <----- when I add this
  replay.classList.add("hidden");
//WHATTT
}
function formatT(Time){
// I get an error here but the classList add works fine
  const res = new Date(Time *1000).toISOString().substr(11,8);
  console.log(res)

  return{
    minutes: res.substr(3,2),
    seconds: res.substr(6,2),
  };
};
```

```js
function intvid(){
  const viddur = Math.round(vid.duration);
  seek.setAttribute('max',viddur)
  progbar.setAttribute('max',viddur)
  const time = formatT(viddur)
  duration.innerText =`${time.minutes}:${time.seconds}`;
  duration.setAttribute('datetime',`${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s`)


}
function updateT(){
  const time = formatT(Math.round(video.currentTime));
  seek.value = Math.floor(vid.currentTime);
  progbar.value = Math.floor(vid.currentTime);
  telapse.innerText= `${time.minutes}:${time.seconds}`;
  telapse.setAttribute('datetime', `${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s`);
}
function updateseek(event){
  const skipto = Math.round((event.offsetX / event.target.clientWidth)* parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('max'),10));
  seek.setAttribute('data-seek', skipto);
  const t = formatT(skipto);
  seekTool.textContent = `${t.minutes}:${t.seconds}`;
  const rect = vid.getBoundingClientRect();
  seekTool.style.left = `${event.pageX-rect.left}px`;
}
```

Comment: " it throws an error on the New Date function" - **What error?**

Comment: @Dai index.js:49 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
    at Date.toISOString (<anonymous>)
    at formatT (index.js:49)
    at HTMLInputElement.updateseek (index.js:77)

Comment: Where are you calling `formatT`? Where is this script running? Please post more context.

Comment: @Dai I added the functions where it is included, do you need more?

Comment: Before calling `new Date()`, try `console.log(Time)` to see what the value is. I'll bet it's `null` or something bogus.

Comment: @kmoser You're right is there anyway to stop myself from getting NaN, and why would that cause it?

Comment: @AndrewHansen Just `console.log()` the values that get passed to `formatT()` right before you call `formatT()` and you'll see where the source of the error is.